# force Javascript to not execute till display ="inline"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a program which contains 2 div's. Depending on the user at any given time 1 of the div's is visible. Is it possible to stop my entire `<script </script>` from executing on till the div which it is in is set to `display="inline"`?

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense as it's worded, but the direct answer is "no".  If you posted more information about what you're trying to do, along with the actual script, you might get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly no. But with jQuery, you *could* override the hide/show functions so that they fire custom events "onshow" and "onhide", then you could bind event handlers to these events to run various code when those events fire.

Comment: You don't really need jquery for that. You can implement it yourself by creating your own wrapper for show/hide

Comment: You are correct. It's just a lot easier with jQuery (and I'm sure other frameworks as well)