# Set Javascript display to "none"

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [force Javascript to not execute till display =“inline”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019463/force-javascript-to-not-execute-till-display-inline)

I've got a div like the following...

```
    <div id="tag" style="width: 360px; display:none">
    <script type="text/javascript">
              Crazy Wizardry Javascript here!
            </script>
    </div>
```

The Javascript inside is displaying.. is there a way that I can force it to not display on till I set the div to display "inline"?

Comment: We might need to see some of the "Crazy Wizardry Javascript", or at least know what it's doing.

Comment: what do you mean "is displaying"??? Do you see the code?

Comment: This is the same as [force Javascript to not execute till display ="inline"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019463/force-javascript-to-not-execute-till-display-inline) — were you planning to ask the same question for every possible value the display property can have?

Comment: I think he thinks that the script won't execute unless the div is visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't display at all: http://jsfiddle.net/XYUpJ/

But this is because that script tag does not output anything into that container.  `script` tags themselves are `display:none` so you should never ever see their content.

If instead you mean you want the script to only *run* when the down that owns it becomes visible, then no you can't do that in this way.  Visibile or not, a script tag just runs.

Instead you want to define a function in a script tag, and call that function when you set the `#tag` to be visible.